# GAS aarch64 syntax to get .ascii string length

Tags: assembly, clang, x86-64, arm64, gnu-assembler

I'm trying to translate this `x86_64` program:

```
# hello_world.s
# GNU Assembly, x86_64 Linux

.global _start

.data

.equ SYS_EXIT, 60
.equ SYS_WRITE, 1
.equ STDOUT, 1
.equ SUCCESS, 0

MSG:
    .ascii "Hello world!\n"

.equ MSG_LEN, . - MSG

.text

_start:
    # write(STDOUT, MSG, MSG_LEN)
    mov $SYS_WRITE, %rax
    mov $STDOUT, %rdi
    mov $MSG, %rsi
    mov $MSG_LEN, %rdx
    syscall

    # exit(SUCCESS)
    mov $SYS_EXIT, %rax
    mov $SUCCESS, %rdi
    syscall
```

Into an `aarch64` program:

```
// hello_world.s
// GNU Assembly, aarch64 Linux

.data

.equ SYS_EXIT, 93
.equ SYS_WRITE, 64
.equ STDOUT, 1
.equ SUCCESS, 0

MSG:
    .ascii "Hello world!\n"

.equ MSG_LEN, . - MSG

.text

.global _start

_start:
    // write(STDOUT, MSG, MSG_LEN)
    mov x8, #SYS_WRITE
    mov x0, #STDOUT
    adr x1, MSG
    mov x2, #MSG_LEN
    svc #0

    // exit(SUCCESS)
    mov x8, #SYS_EXIT
    mov x0, #SUCCESS
    svc #0
```

However when I try to assemble the above program I get this error:

```
hello_world.s:27:13: error: expected compatible register or logical immediate
    mov x2, #MSG_LEN
            ^
```

Which I think is somewhat of a red herring because if I change this line:

```
.equ MSG_LEN, . - MSG
```

Into this:

```
.equ MSG_LEN, 13
```

Then it works fine. However I'm not happy with this solution because I don't want to hardcode the `MSG_LEN`, I want the assembler to be able to determine the length at assemble time like in the `x86_64` version. Can you help me figure out how I can set `MSG_LEN` in the `aarch64` version of the program without having to explicitly hardcode a value?

Additional details: I'm compiling and running these programs inside of a docker container which is built from this Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install clang qemu qemu-system gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
```

I'm compiling and running the `x86_64` program with:

```
clang -nostdlib -target x86_64-linux-gnu -s hello_world.s -o hello_world.out && ./hello_world.out
```

And I'm compiling and running the `aarch64` program with:

```
clang -nostdlib -target aarch64-linux-gnu -s hello_world.s -o hello_world.out && ./hello_world.out
```

Comment: You seem to be using clang not gnu assembler. Gnu assembler v2.25.1 has no problem with the code.

Comment: @Jester yes, clang has its own "integrated assembler" but it's suppose to be a drop-in replacement for GAS in the same way clang is a drop-in replacement for gcc. I've been using the clang assembler while following a bunch of different GAS tutorials & examples and have had no issues compiling or running anything.

Comment: Sorry I can't test with clang, but the code seems fine for gas. Generates `d28001a2 mov x2, #0xd` as expected.

Comment: I can reproduce the error with clang.  I think this is a bug in the clang assembler.

Comment: `.equ SYS_EXIT, 93` - don't define these yourself; `#include <sys/syscall.h>` or `<asm/unistd.h>` to use glibc / Linux's definitions of `SYS_exit` or `__NR_exit` (respectively).  Building a `.S` file with gcc or clang will run it through the C preprocessor before assembling.  (And those headers don't contain any C prototypes or anything, just #define and #if stuff, so they're compatible with asm.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: I needed to use `-fno-integrated-as` with `clang` to tell it to use GNU Assembler directly instead of its own built-in integrated assembler (which is *suppose* to be a drop-in replacement for GAS but apparently it's not). I used the following updated command to compile and run my `aarch64` program without issue:

```
clang -nostdlib -fno-integrated-as -target aarch64-linux-gnu -s hello_world.s -o hello_world.out && ./hello_world.out
```

Thanks to @Jester and @Nate Eldredge who helped me debug in the comments.